# Crystal Report: Conditional Base count in Report footer

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

i have following records in crystal report

```
ID   Number   Status
 1   001       En
 2   002       En
 3   003       Suc
 4   004       En
```

exacted output

```
ID   Number   Status
 1   001       En
 2   002       En
 3   003       Suc
 4   004       En

    Total En=  3
    Total Suc= 1
```

i want to count Total in Report Footer  .use below formula but not work

```
if({sp;1.Status} = "En") then
count({sp;1.ID})
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula doesn't work this way. try this:

create two more formula `calen` and `calsuc` and place to the side of the status in details and suppress both:

calen

```
if({sp;1.Status} = "En") then
1
else
0
```

calsuc

```
if({sp;1.Status} = "suc") then
1
else
0
```

Now take the summary of both the formulas in report footer and display as you like